# How to get credit debit total for last 3 month via mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I need total of credit and debit for last three month.What I am doing right now it get sum of credit and sum of debit, then I subtract credit with debit  which is not right please help me with this.

I need (credit - debit ) for last three month for single user.But right now it goes in minus which is incorrect.Credit and Debit records should not be in negative(-ve). Credit expire in every 3 months

my table is as below

```
CREATE TABLE `cb_customer_credit_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ord_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `coupon_assignee` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `coupon_assigned_to_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `coupon_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `coupon_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `coupon_amount` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `coupon_dis_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `amount` float(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `cr_dr` enum('C','D') NOT NULL,
  `order_note` text NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified_on` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `cb_customer_credit_log` (`id`, `ord_id`, `coupon_assignee`, `coupon_assigned_to_id`, `coupon_id`, `coupon_code`, `coupon_amount`, `coupon_dis_type`, `amount`, `cr_dr`, `order_note`, `created_on`, `modified_on`) VALUES
(1, '3327', 'pranav.patel@cc.com', 'marmik.p@cc.com', '2953', 'demo_code1', '10', 'fixed_cart', 10.00, 'C', 'new order credit', '2019-05-15 11:48:18', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(5, '3350', 'pranav.patel@cc.com', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 9.00, 'D', 'credit used by user', '2019-08-23 07:34:31', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(9, '3359', 'pranav.patel@cc.com', 'marmik.p@cc.com', '2953', 'demo_code1', '10', 'fixed_cart', 0.50, 'C', 'new order credit', '2019-08-23 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(11, '3373', 'pranav.patel@cc.com', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 1.00, 'D', 'credit used by user', '2019-08-23 12:47:35', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(12, '3378', 'marmik.p@cc.com', 'jayesh.b@cc.com', '2953', 'demo_code1', '10', 'fixed_cart', 0.50, 'C', 'new order credit', '2019-08-23 13:00:20', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');





-----My Query -----
SELECT 
    SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN cr_dr = 'C' THEN amount END,0)) - 
    SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN cr_dr = 'D' THEN amount END,0)) balance 
    FROM 
        cb_customer_credit_log 
    WHERE 
        coupon_assignee = 'pranav.patel@cc.com'
     AND 
        created_on >= now() - interval 3 month
```

Above query is not working for me for last three month data

Comment: What is your expected output ? Add that bit to the question in tabular text format.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your Answer is correct.
Give a try to below queries:
For Specific(conditional) User:

```
select coupon_assignee, 
    SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN cr_dr = 'C' THEN amount END,0)) AS `Total Credit`,
    SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN cr_dr = 'D' THEN amount END,0)) AS `Total Debit`,
    ((SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN cr_dr = 'C' THEN amount END,0))) - (SUM(COALESCE(CASE 
    WHEN cr_dr = 'D' THEN amount END,0))))   AS `Total Balance` 
from cb_customer_credit_log
where coupon_assignee = 'pranav.patel@cc.com' 
AND created_on >= now() - interval 3 month;
```

For All User:

```
select coupon_assignee, 
    SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN cr_dr = 'C' THEN amount END,0)) AS `Total Credit`,
    SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN cr_dr = 'D' THEN amount END,0)) AS `Total Debit`,
    ((SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN cr_dr = 'C' THEN amount END,0))) - (SUM(COALESCE(CASE 
    WHEN cr_dr = 'D' THEN amount END,0))))   AS `Total Balance` 
from cb_customer_credit_log
where created_on >= now() - interval 3 month
group by coupon_assignee;
```

For Combined User:

```
select
    SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN cr_dr = 'C' THEN amount END,0)) AS `Total Credit`,
    SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN cr_dr = 'D' THEN amount END,0)) AS `Total Debit`,
    ((SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN cr_dr = 'C' THEN amount END,0))) - (SUM(COALESCE(CASE 
    WHEN cr_dr = 'D' THEN amount END,0))))   AS `Total Balance` 
from cb_customer_credit_log
where created_on >= now() - interval 3 month;
```

Comment: @PranavPatel -9.5 is what I would expect

Comment: yeah according to you and data it is right but how can some one's credit goes in minus....it is against logic....credit expire in 3 month.